# Dynamically Generate Javascript Code from Server - MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

I am using MVC 4 Web Api and I have a requirement to expose a end point which can be consumed by clients to render code on their web page. Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server/endpoint"/>
```

When the above line is included in web pages, the server should return a javascript code which should be automatically executed.

For example if the server returns the code - `alert('hello')`, then the client webpage (using the script) should automatically pop up "hello".

The server side code can be like below. In this case, the server returns javacript code to write a table in the browser. Basically this is used to return list of publications for a  particular professor in the University. The enpoint is exposed so that individuals can include the script in their web pages to show their publications

```
// GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {

            var html = "<table><tbody>";
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>row 1, col 1</td>";
            html += "<td>row 1, col 2</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>row 2, col 1</td>";
            html += "<td>row 2, col 2</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            html += "</tbody></table>";
            var script = string.Format(@"<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('{0}')</script>", html);
            return script;
        }
```

Any thoughts how this can be achieved. I tried using `Response.Write("alert('hello')")` but it does not work.

Comment: Have you considered using a [HttpHandler](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - If you will use the endpoint in script tag you don't need to rewrite the script tag inside de get method.

2 - The code you are trying to return isn't a javascript code, this is a html code and will not run when called but script tag.

3 - try to do this:

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server/endpoint"/>
```

webAPI:

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "alert('hello world');";
}
```

Comment: Does it work for you? My end point is - http://localhost:49209/. I have a ajax get when a request comes to the endpoint - $.get('/api/values/5') and it returns string - "alert('hello')";. This is treated as html string rather getting executed as javascript code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tried like my example? In my example I am not using a ajax call, I am using the end point in script´s tag src. Like you asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an WCF service with a REST endpoint, and my script was also being treated as a string as it was received quoted between double quotes.

`"alert('hello world');"` instead of `alert('hello world');`

I found the solution here:
https://viswaug.wordpress.com/2008/05/22/customizing-the-response-serialization-in-wcf-rest-services/

You have to set the content type of the response to `application/x-javascript` and wrap your string inside a MemoryStream, like this:

```
public Stream GetSomeScript()
{
    WebOperationContext context = WebOperationContext.Current;
    context.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";

    const string TEXT_TO_SEND = "alert('hello world');";

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    sw.Write(TEXT_TO_SEND);
    sw.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Hope this helps.